# Unable to clear line when using readline prompt / setPrompt in Node

Tags: node.js, console, prompt

I'm having trouble clearing a line in `stdout` when using [`readline prompt`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_rl_prompt_preservecursor).

I code similar to this:

```
import readline from 'readline'

const rl = readline.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout)
let input = ''

readline.emitKeypressEvents(process.stdin)
process.stdin.on('keypress', registerInput)

function registerInput (str, key) {
  if (key.name === 'backspace') {
    input = input.slice(0, input.length - 1)
  } else {
    input += str
  }
  if (input === '42') {
    input = ''
    console.log(' ✓')
    nextPrompt()
  }
}

function nextPrompt () {
  readline.clearLine(process.stdout, 0)
  rl.setPrompt('What is the meaning of life? ')
  rl.prompt()
}

nextPrompt()
```

In the real code, arithmetic questions are generated.

[Here is a screen capture of the output](https://asciinema.org/a/e2pfqvzr2wkkjvp8l5ra2wnhh).

### What happens

The cursor resets (using `.prompt(false)` keeps cursor in position), but the input is still there in the new prompt.

### Expected

The input `42` should not appear in the new prompt on the next line.

Why am I using `.on('keypress'` instead of `rl.on('line'`? I want the response in the game to be snap, avoiding pressing *enter*.

What I have tried:

- `readline.clearLine(process.stdout, -1)`
- `readline.clearLine(process.stdout, 1)`
- `readline.clearLine(process.stdin, 0)`
- `process.stdout.clearLine()`

### Environment

I'm using node v6.0.0 and babel-cli v6.7.7 (here babel just for the import statement, but in the real code I use [object-rest-spread](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread) and therefor need babel). [Here is a gist of the generated code](https://gist.github.com/arve0/bafb14f1848a1c9bbb45903450393625) if you do not have babel installed.

### Question

Is `rl.prompt` incompatible with `readline.clearLine`? How can this be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
import readline from 'readline'

let input = ''
let question = 'What is the meaning of life? '

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
})
readline.emitKeypressEvents(process.stdin)
process.stdin.on('keypress', registerInput)

function registerInput (str, key) {
  if (key.name === 'backspace') {
    input = input.slice(0, input.length - 1)
  } else {
    const numbers = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0'.split(' ')
    if (numbers.indexOf(str) !== -1) {
      input += str
    }
  }
  if (input === '42') {
    console.log(' ✓')
    input = ''
  }
  render(question, input)
}

function render (question, input) {
  readline.clearLine(process.stdout, 0)
  readline.cursorTo(process.stdout, 0)
  process.stdout.write(question + input)
}

render(question, input)
```

But the question remains, why is `rl.prompt` incompatible with `readline.clearLine`?

I'm guessing that `prompt` does something similar to my approach behind the curtains. A `resetPromptInput` would be nice.